# How to add new rows to Pandas data frame based on calculation using all rows for a given datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, row

I have the following data frame that consists of device electricity usage in my home broken up by hour.

```
             DateTime                   Name    kWh
0     1/31/2024 18:00              Sump Pump  0.003
1     1/31/2024 18:00              Furnace 2  0.027
2     1/31/2024 18:00              Furnace 1  0.211
3     1/31/2024 18:00                  Dryer  0.302
4     1/31/2024 18:00            Total Usage  1.927
5     1/31/2024 18:00              Always On  0.811
6     1/31/2024 18:00                 Heat 7  0.003
7     1/31/2024 18:00                 Fridge  0.030
8     1/31/2024 18:00                   Pump  0.069
9     1/31/2024 19:00              Sump Pump  0.002
10    1/31/2024 19:00            Total Usage  1.593
11    1/31/2024 19:00              Always On  0.828
12    1/31/2024 19:00                 Heat 7  0.001
13    1/31/2024 19:00                 Fridge  0.02
14    1/31/2024 19:00                   Pump  0.070
```

I would like to add a row for every hour where Name = "Other" and kWh equals ("Total Usage" kWh - the sum of kWh for all other rows for that hour) so the resulting data frame would be the following.  The Names, order, and number of rows for each hour will vary. (Note I added 2 rows where Name = "Other".

```
             DateTime                   Name    kWh
0     1/31/2024 18:00              Sump Pump  0.003
1     1/31/2024 18:00              Furnace 2  0.027
2     1/31/2024 18:00              Furnace 1  0.211
3     1/31/2024 18:00                  Dryer  0.302
4     1/31/2024 18:00            Total Usage  1.927
5     1/31/2024 18:00              Always On  0.811
6     1/31/2024 18:00                 Heat 7  0.003
7     1/31/2024 18:00                 Fridge  0.030
8     1/31/2024 18:00                   Pump  0.069
9     1/31/2024 18:00                  Other  0.471
10    1/31/2024 19:00              Sump Pump  0.002
11    1/31/2024 19:00            Total Usage  1.593
12    1/31/2024 19:00              Always On  0.828
13    1/31/2024 19:00                 Heat 7  0.001
14    1/31/2024 19:00                 Fridge  0.02
15    1/31/2024 19:00                   Pump  0.070
16    1/31/2024 19:00                  Other  0.672
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi, could you post some code ? What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  could group on time and sum the kWh for each group; the basic approach is shown in the simplified code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [18, 18, 19, 19],
                   'Name' : ['a', 'z', 'a', 'z'],
                   'kWh': [1.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.1]
                })

df2 = df.groupby('time', as_index = False)['kWh'].sum()

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2]).fillna('Other').sort_values('time').reset_index(drop = True)

print(df3)
```

which gives:

```
   time   Name  kWh
0    18      a  1.2
1    18      z  3.2
2    18  Other  4.4
3    19      a  4.2
4    19      z  5.1
5    19  Other  9.3
```

Comment: Thank you.  This definately points me in right direction.  I now need to figure out how to exclude the rows where Name = "Total Usage" from the sum, and then subtract that sum from the "Total Usage" for each hour. My first thought is to move the kWh for all the "Total Usage" rows to their own column prior to the groupby. Do the subtraction of the new "Total Usage" column - the sum of the other values in the original colum into a new column.  And then modify the columns in the dataframe resulting from the groupby to that I can concat it with the original frame.  I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df_temp = df.copy()
# Create new column for kWh where Name=Total Usage
df_temp['kWh_Tot'] = np.where(df_temp['Name'] == 'Total Usage', df_temp['kWh'], np.nan)
# Set kWh to zero for rows where Name = Total Usage
df_temp['kWh'] = np.where(df_temp['Name'] == 'Total Usage', np.nan, df_temp['kWh'])
# Group by hour and sum kWh and kWh_Total columns
df2 = df_temp.groupby('DateTime').aggregate({'kWh':'sum','kWh_Tot':'sum'})
#Subract kWh from total kWh to get total for Other category
df2['kWh'] = df2['kWh_Tot']  - df2['kWh']
#Drop kWh Total because all we are interested in is Other 
df2 = df2.drop(columns=['kWh_Tot'])
# Add 'Name' column where all values 'Other' for union/concat
df2['Name'] = 'Other'
df2.reset_index(inplace = True)
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2]).sort_values('DateTime').reset_index(drop = True)
#Optional delete rows where Name = 'Total Usage' because redundant
df3 = df3[df3.Name != 'Total Usage']

print(df3.to_string())
```

Resulting in the following with the 'Total Usage' columns removed:

```
7      1/1/2024 10:00                 Fridge  0.027
8      1/1/2024 10:00                 Heat 7  0.002
10     1/1/2024 10:00              Always On  0.662
11     1/1/2024 10:00              Furnace 2  0.024
12     1/1/2024 10:00                  Other  0.443
13     1/1/2024 10:00              Furnace 1  0.134
14     1/1/2024 11:00                  Other  0.772
15     1/1/2024 11:00              Furnace 2  0.061
16     1/1/2024 11:00              Furnace 1  0.003
18     1/1/2024 11:00              Always On  0.662
19     1/1/2024 11:00                 Heat 7  0.001
20     1/1/2024 11:00                 Fridge  0.027
```